# node.js app hangs after making a lot of client requests

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node.js app that uses a lot of client request connections. After a certain number of successes, they start to hang, even when timeouts are set. This is node.js v4.2.1.

I am limiting the number of client requests that are made at any one time, and I am using `require('active-handles').print()` to display the details of what is hanging, once the hang is detected. The results are:

```
onread: net.js:501:15 (net client connection, fd = 9)
function onread(nread, buffer) {
    ...
}

onread: net.js:501:15 (net client connection, fd = 11)
Count: 2. Source printed above

onread: net.js:501:15 (net client connection, fd = 12)
Count: 3. Source printed above
```

My question is, how do I prevent the hang, and why won't open connections obey the timeout and terminate? What can I do to debug and fix this?

Comment: Please let me know if you figure this out.